# How to show a Outlook-like toast from Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, outlook, growl, node-webkit

I would like to show a message that basically looks like the "toast" of Outlook (or a Growl notication on OS X). I want to show that message from a node-webkit application in a way that works on OS X, Linux and Windows without any changes (if this does not work, you may skip Linux).

How could I do this?

So far I have seen that I could use [node-growl](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-growl), but the setup for the various operating systems is a little bit, well, clumsy.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty bleeding edge so support is spotty in older browsers, but you could try doing something with the new(ish) [notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)

```
var notification = new Notification(title, options)
```

I'm no expert on the subject, but if you find the MDN documentation less than helpful, you could try out [this tutorial](http://www.paulund.co.uk/html5-notifications).

And finally, if you'd like a javascript library to abstract this for you: [Notify.js](http://alxgbsn.co.uk/2013/02/20/notify-js-a-handy-wrapper-for-the-web-notifications-api/)